# Thicker outer table border with border-collapse in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am using a table with border-collapse and it all works fine in Chrome, Safari etc but on Firefox the outer border is thicker. Firefox is on the left below and Chrome on the right

[image]

See http://codepen.io/benpalmer/pen/JsFlq

1px borders seem fine but anything larger and the outer border seems thicker

I've tried adding `border-spacing:0px;` to the table but with no luck

Anybody have idea ideas to this bug?